# Is there a built-in method to replace booleans in pandas dataframe with a string value?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I try to find a factory solution in pandas (or numpy) to solve a boolean values replacement.

I use a list comprehension with type check and builtin functions.

```py
some_data = pd.Series([False, 0, True, 1])
tmp = [str(value).lower() if type(value) is bool else value for value in some_data]
some_new_data = pd.Series(tmp)
```

Is there any other solution to this? Using some features from pandas or numpy?

Comment: `series.astype(str).str.lower()` ?

Comment: It's fine with this simple example, but if data contains other string values it will lower them as well and I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
# create mask
mask = some_data.apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, bool))

tmp = np.where(mask, some_data.astype(str).str.lower(), some_data.values)
some_new_data = pd.Series(tmp)
print(some_new_data)
```

**Output**

```
0    false
1        0
2     true
3        1
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is there a way to speed it up? Presented 'standard' Python solution is ~2.5x  faster.

Comment: @czilibili I cannot think of one, perhaps using the list comprehension is faster